# Avoid "write partial file"?

Tags: macvim

I use MacVim.

I write-to-file frequently using ":w".

I often have some lines selected visually when I do this, and get an annoying "Write partial file" dialogue (which more annoyingly doesn't tab out to "No").

Writing a partial file is something I do very seldom.

What are your recommendations to make the default skip "Write partial file" and just write the entire file?

Of course I'd like to develop a new mapping for the default functionality (in case I do need it).

I tried:

```
command w <esc>w
```

However, I could not save that command because "User defined commands must start with capital letters".

Next, I tried this, but get "Not an editor command ^[w"

```
command! WriteIgnoreVisual <esc>w
cabbrev w <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'WriteIgnoreVisual' : 'w')<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close.  It's easier to use an `<expr>` mapping.  You just have to check that the cmdline equals the string `'<,'>w`, and if so, delete the existing command line and replace it with a plain `:w`.

```
cabbrev <expr> w getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdline() == "'<,'>w" ? '<c-u>w' : 'w'
```

Comment: Nice, thank you so much that worked sweetly. I don't grok what the "c-u" does though? I thought I had to do <esc>, why "c-u" is preferred?

Comment: `<c-u>` deletes the existing cmdline.  you need to stay in cmdline to issue `:w`, but `<esc>` would drop you out into normal mode instead.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I was leaving command mode with <esc>. You the man, Mass!